# Cannot subclass SChartCrosshairTooltip

Tags: ios, shinobi

I'm trying to subclass `SChartCrosshairTooltip` with 2.2.1 version of Shinobi Chart Library:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ShinobiCharts/SChartCrosshairTooltip.h>

@interface Tooltip : SChartCrosshairTooltip

@end
```

No matter what I do, I always get this error:

> ShinobiCharts Trial 2.2.1/Demos/LineChart/ShinobiCharts.embeddedframework/ShinobiCharts.framework/Headers/SChartCrosshairTooltip.h:21:5: Unknown type name 'SChartCrosshairStyle'; did you mean 'SChartCrosshairTooltip'?

as if it was impossible to subclass the `SChartCrosshairTooltip` differently from what documentation says.

I cannot switch to newer versions of the library (now is 2.5.0), but I really need to customize the crosshair tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this isn't working is because `SChartCrosshairStyle` is forward-defined in `SChartCrosshairTooltip`. I think that you could get around this by adding an import for `SChartCrosshairStyle`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ShinobiCharts/SChartCrosshairStyle.h>
#import <ShinobiCharts/SChartCrosshairTooltip.h>
```

...however, there are other forward definitions inside `SChartCrosshairTooltip`, so I suspect that you will get other unknown class issues.

The recommended way is to use the common Shinobi header import:

```
#import <ShinobiCharts/ShinobiChart.h>
```

This will import all the relevant classes.

Comment: Thanks. Easy to get lost in so simple things.

Comment: This caught me too, quite subtly. Autocomplete did not help. `#import <ShinobiCharts/ShinobiChart.h>` != `#import <ShinobiCharts/ShinobiCharts.h>` (which works but is wrong)